# How to access a windows server from ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking

Currently I can get into this windows server by typing in \\SERVERNAME.

How can I do this on my linux machine?
By the way i cant see the server on my windows machine I can only get there by typing that in.

Thanks!

Comment: there are two backslashes in front of SERVERNAME

Comment: Also I cnat see that server in my windows file explorer... I need to type it in to the bar

Comment: Please be a little more specific: Do you want to access your Windows server via network shares or just _somehow_, e.g. with Remote Desktop? Also, where do you see the Windows server? Is it in "My Network Places" on your Ubuntu machine? Please have a look on [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide).

Answer (score 6):

Open a file browser, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then type **smb://servername** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux there are a couple ways to either connect one time or permanently connect each time you're logged on. In File Browser you can use the menu item File -> Connect To Server and choose Windows Share and input the path to your windows share. Or you could edit /etc/fstab with the correct file system mount point and it would reconnect or remap your share each time you logon.

Although, IMHO The best way to manage Windows / Linux shares is using Samba from the Linux environment and connect that direction each time, it will be much more friendly.

Answer (score 1):

In Nautilus address bar, you type:

```
smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Replace the xs' with the IP address of the Windows server. If you are running a firewall, you need to keep Samba ports open for outgoing connections.

Answer (score 1):

As a System Administrator or home user, connecting to Windows Computers from Ubuntu with just file sharing is all that may be needed. Other times, there is a need to remotely access Windows Computers to perform more complex tasks. With Windows, you can easily connect to another Windows Computer running Terminal Services with a Terminal Server client. On Ubuntu, you can also access any Windows Computer using tsclient.

tsclient is a GNOME program for remotely accessing Microsoft Windows NT/2000/2003 Terminal Services and XP Remote Desktop Sharing over RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol).

With Ubuntu, tsclient is installed by default. To verify it is installed simply enter the following command in a Terminal window:
dpkg –get-selections | grep tsclient
If tsclient is installed you should see the output of the command as:
tsclient             installed

If tsclient is not installed, you can install it by executing the following command from a Terminal window:
sudo apt-get install tsclient

Now that tsclient is installed, you can easily open tsclient by typing tsclient at the Terminal prompt (yes it looks exactly as the Terminal Server client on Windows!)

To quickly connect to a Windows Computer, just enter the hostname in the Computer field and click Connect at the bottom of tsclient.

[image]

Once connected you can logon to the Windows Computer as normal: 
[image]

Just as you can save configuration settings on a Windows Terminal Server Client, the same can done with tsclient by setting options in the Dislpay, Local Resources, Programs, or Performance tabs. Once the settings have been configured, you can save it as a file and open it when you need to connect to the server.

Once you have saved the settings to a file, you can quickly connect to a Windows Computer from a Terminal window instead of running tsclient from the GUI. To see the tsclient command prompt options, type:

tsclient –help

tsclient [OPTIONS]… [FILE]…

FILE                an rdp format file containing options
-h, –help        display this help and exit
-v, –version     output version information and exit
-x FILE            launch rdesktop with options specified in FILE

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had to remote access a windows server from my Ubuntu, the existing answers in here didn't work for me, but installing **Remmina worked fine**

To install Remmina terminal in and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-* libfreerdp-plugins-standard
```

and the Remmina application will be available in your Ubuntu applications.
Then, open the Remmina fill the windows server credentials and have a remote access.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Remmina is a good tool for Ubuntu users. It supports rdp and vnc and the installation is so easy. Personally, I prefer to install it using snap. `sudo snap install remmina`.  Get more insights here: [ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/access-remote-desktop#1-overview)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1231340)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).